# Let's migrate 'immigration'

Tags: discussion, tags

There is an [immigration](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration) tag, but no [emigration](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emigration) or [migration](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration).

I suggest creating [migration](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) and making the other two synonyms.

One country's emigration is another country's immigration.

Background:

- Currently [1 question tagged *immigration*](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration)
- Currently [1 question containing the text *emigration*](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+emigration), [4 containing *immigration*](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+immigration), [8 containing *migration*](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+migration).

<del>Not a large disruption to edit those</del>
I have edited the questions. The tag hierarchy still needs to be updated by someone with enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea. The essence of tag and questions is around the movement of people or potentially animals.

Comment: I have retagged the questions, but don't have the rep to do anything about the tag hierarchy.

Comment: OK, I made the tag synonyms https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all